# Javascript Test Format If Statements Error

Tags: javascript

When I add the test format as an if statement to the javascript code, it only shows that there is any error for a fraction of a second and then disappears. While if I remove the test format, the errors show fine. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Settings</title>

  <style>
      .entry, textarea {
        float: right;
        width: 500px;
        resize: none;
        padding: 1px;
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
    <h1 style="margin-top: 0px">Settings</h1>
    <form onSubmit="return checkForm(this)">
        <label for="username" class="label"> Change Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" class="entry"/></br>
        <p class=error id="usernameError"><?php echo $error;?></p>
        <br/>

        <label for="email" class="label"> Change E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="entry"/> <br/>
        <p class=error id="firstnameError"></p>
        <br/>

        <label for="password" class="label">Change Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="entry"/> <br/>
        <p class=error id="passwordError"></p>
        <br/>

        <label for="confirmPassword" class="label">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="confirmpassword" class = "entry"/>
        <br/>
        <p class=error id="confirmpasswordError"></p>
        <br/>

        <label for="address" class="label">Change Address:</label>
        <textarea id = "address" rows="3" class="entry"></textarea><br/><br/><br/><br/>

        <label for="mobile" class="label">Change Mobile Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="mobile" class="entry"/> <br/><br/><br/>
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" id="confirm" name="confirm" value="Confirm Changes" style= "font-size: 15px; background: #f5f5f5;
         width: 20%; margin-right: 20%" class="entry" />
    </form>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function checkForm(form){  
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var mailformat = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        var usernameformat = /^[\w ]+$/;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
        var ok = true; 

        if (!usernameformat.test(username))
        {  
            document.getElementById("usernameError").innerHTML = "No symbols please!";
            ok = false;  
        } 

        if (password!=confirmpassword)
        {  
            document.getElementById("passwordError").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
            document.getElementById("confirmpasswordError").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match";
            ok = false;  
        }
        if (!mailformat.test(email)) {
             document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "Input a valid email";
                ok = false; 
               }

    return ok;

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read your Error Console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: I know it's bad form. But for the sake of the question it's embedded in the HTML file between the script tags in the end.

Comment: Your email error field is called `firstnameError`, not `emailError`. Pay attention to the JS error console, and always check your assumptions, e.g., you can type in `document.getElementById("emailError")` to the console and see that no such element exists.

Comment: do you have a `test` function somewhere?

Comment: @ewizard It is a regular expression method......

Comment: oh i see i think u want regex `match`

Comment: @epascarello probably submitting form due to error preventing the `return`. OP seeing error only momentarily

Comment: @ewizard ... Not the issue, that simply changes the way you do the regex test.

Comment: cool never seen test before

Comment: Also `email` is not defined anywhere. That will throw error

Comment: @charlietfl so OP needs to set the checkbox to not clear the console on page navigation OR break on errors.

Comment: @charlietfl well email will not throw an error because it is defined with an id on an input, but that is a bug also.

Comment: do you need `return` here? `return checkForm(this)`. it is already returning `ok` to `onSubmit`? i would try it without the `return`

Comment: im not sure if you should even be returning `ok` to `onsubmit` as a `boolean`...`onsubmit` just allows you to execute a function...it doesnt take values back

Comment: @ewizard No, if you return a falsey value the form won't be submitted.

Comment: @DaveNewton does he need that `return` in the `onsubmit` if his function is returning?

Comment: @ewizard If you want to the browser to do anything besides just run the code there, yes.

Comment: @DaveNewton i dont doubt you just trying to understand isnt the form being submitted already when that function runs (the browser doing something)?  It needs the return value to complete it or something?

Comment: @ewizard No, the form will be submitted if the validation function returns something truthy. There are other errors (noted in comments and (at least partially) correct answer) causing the email validation not to occur.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice `<p class=error id="firstnameError"></p>`?

```
<label for="email" class="label"> Change E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="entry"/> <br/>
    <p class=error id="firstnameError"></p>
    <br/>
```

It should be: `emailError`:

```
<label for="email" class="label"> Change E-mail:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" class="entry"/> <br/>
<p class=error id="emailError"></p>
<br/>
```

`document.getElementById("emailError")` is undefined, so when you attempt to set the html, it will fail.

`email` is also not defined anywhere. If you want to test against email, ensure you have setup the variable properly:

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

Comment: Was not me, but people do tend to downvote on answers to typos. Typos are normally a close vote. In this case it was more than just a typo, but a basic mistake.

Comment: That was perfect. I can't believe I didn't catch that. I'll use the JS error console next time as well (didn't know it existed). Sorry, but thanks

Comment: lol...3 downvotes. You people are mad. Sure there were some simple errors, but I provided a solution and the reasoning behind why each error was happening. Don't knock me, knock the OP.

Comment: -1 since it's not the type of question which should be answered - Stack Overflow is not a debugging service, don't make it look like one

Comment: @nicael Then downvote the question and ignore the answer. It's not cool to penalize people who try to help.

Comment: @Dave, I'm down voting the answer so as to tell Franker that it's not good to answer such questions. I've downvoted the question either.
It's just off-topic here. Imagine someone asks a question about bike sheds on Stack Overflow and that question gets answered - it would be the similar situation.

Comment: @nicael I tell people by telling them, not by penalizing them. Note also that this is the general policy: good answers on bad questions should not be penalized, e.g., https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281795/438992, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions